# Accessing the workshet with openpyxl. Which methot is faster?

Tags: python, openpyxl, timeit

I am refactoring a small project which bases on openpyxl to analyze .xlsx inputs. I am trying to reduce time needed for it to do its job and currently trying methods for accessing cell values of Excel worksheet.

I tested two methods (code below) with timeit and one of them seems to be twice as fast as first one.

```py
import timeit
from openpyxl.reader.excel import ExcelReader

samplesPath = r'path_to_excel_file'

workbook = ExcelReader(samplesPath)
workbook.read()

worksheet = workbook.wb['Sheet1']

def func1():
    for i in range(1,10):
        worksheet.cell(i,1).value = 'value'

def func2():
    for i in range(1,10):
        workbook.wb['Sheet1'].cell(i,1).value = 'value'

print(timeit.timeit(func1))
print(timeit.timeit(func2))
```

Timeit scores:

func1 = 29.23
func2 = 51.07

Can someone explain me the difference between saving worksheet as variable, and then accessing the cell value with it, and accessing it when calling a worksheet every time?

How does it vary in the background, and if there is even faster method?

Comment: If you're posting a code with `timeit`, it will be a good idea to actually post the times...

Comment: @Tomerikoo  Sorry, forgot about this one. Added to post

Comment: openpyxl does include some benchmark code and results but, please, feel free to ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not about `openpyxl` per-se. Yes, you are using openpyxl, but your question is more general and could be applied to many other scenarios.

Now, you are not really using *two methods* for accessing cells. You are using exactly one, the only difference is how you access the sheet.

In `func1` you are using the `worksheet` object and accessing its cells.

In `func2` you are adding another action, which is also accessing the sheet on each iteration. Doing `workbook.wb['Sheet1']` means accessing the sheets pool of the workbook and getting the one with name 'Sheet1'. You are doing that on **every iteration**, so of course that will take more time than using the pre-fetched sheet.

---

Apart from that, that does seem like a lot of time and part of it might be with how you open the file. Seems like you're overly complexing it. Try doing:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(path)
worksheet = workbook['Sheet1']
```

Comment: Actually, there should be no difference between them as worksheets are loaded into memory when a workbook is read. However, the user is deliberately using openpyxl internals for the calls.

Comment: @CharlieClark not sure I understand. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: `load_workbook()` will read the workbooks and every child object so that accessing sheets from workbook is just a dictionary lookup. For whatever reason the poster is using internal code from the library, which is why his workbook is `wookbook.wb` but the calls are the same and do not explain the discrepancies he's claiming.

Comment: @CharlieClark I agree the getting the sheet shouldn't take much time, it is just a loop on the sheets that shouldn't be bigger than, say 10. But, it is still added computation. What do you suggest is the cause for such big difference?

Comment: GIGO – the docs contain much better comparative tests and hotspots have been profiled. `timeit()` is the wrong tool for what is essentially an integration.